# Proving restricted $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability

Given $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ a measurable space and $B\in\mathcal{F}$, show that
$$\mathcal{F}(B):=\{ A\cap B:A\in\mathcal{F} \}$$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Is really easy to show that $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ are in $\mathcal{F}(B)$ and I've already showed that a countable union of sets also belongs to $\mathcal{F}(B)$ but I'm struggling when I try to prove the complement belongs to $\mathcal{F}(B)$.

I know, $(A\cap B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$ and $A^c\in\mathcal{F}(B)$ but I haven't found a way to prove that $B^c\in\mathcal{F}(B)$. Or if there's another way to prove that if $A\cap B\in\mathcal{F}$ then its complement is also in $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: How can $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}(B)$ unless $B = \Omega$ itself? You need to show that this is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$. So, in fact, you need to compute $B \setminus (A \cap B)$ and see if this belongs to $\mathcal{F}(B)$.

Comment: It is stated that $B \in F$ so this implies that $B^{c} \in F$.

Comment: $\mathcal F(B)$ is a $\sigma-$algebra on $B$, not on $\Omega$.

Comment: Fix the problem statement.